# Oxyplot: another value in label

Tags: wpf, oxyplot

is it possible to show another value in a label of a series or to compute the value for a label?
Background: I need a columnseries with TimeSpan-Values. I can use the Axis.LabelFormatter to show Timespan values on the axis. But there is no LabelFormatter for the series. How can I show Timespan values in the labels?

Comment: Create a TimeSpanAxis. Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969656/irregular-interval-on-datetime-axis-in-oxyplot

Comment: But I need Timespan values in a ColumnSeries. And the ColumnSeries needs ColumnItems with _double_ or _int_ values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I figured it out for myself. A use a own class, derived from ColumnItem, with a additional property with the value I need. And in the LabelFormatString (or TrackerFormatString) I can use this property (*LabelFormatString = "{PropertyName}"*)